# Download deb packages with download manager instead of apt?

Tags: package-management, downloads

Hi there I know that deb packages I downloaded are in: `/var/cache/apt/archives/`
And I can save them for future use. However, there is a problem when I download a package using the `apt-get` command, download speed is too slow. When I download files with a download manager I can get up to 1MB/s!

How can I get the URL of the package and download it with a download manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the packages you want to download (and their dependencies) on the [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com) site. Though it's not recommended - you should be able to gather the links from there and use a download manager to retrieve them.

[image: showing download links]
*Dependencies are listed first, then the download section is shown below the related packages*

If you're having slow download times from the official mirrors - try updating your mirror location as it may be that the particular mirror you're fetching from is far away or having latency issues.

Comment: thanks but I did not find any link to download! can you help me more!

Answer (score 1):

synapitc allows you to save url download list, then you can supply it to download manager. you can also save your selection. later load the download list to synaptic.

Comment: use text editor to replace "wget -c " with "" in file download list (at beginning of each line - replace all). hack this.

on windows: you can use free download manager "file->import->import list of downloads" to generate download list you can safely download.

this for bronze badge.